# Small field recorder bags (for large handhelds?)

Tags: transport-bag, cases

I'm looking for a smaller size field recorder bag for my fostex fr le and or my roland R 26, as well as bits n bobs like cables, batteries, tape, mini tripods etc etc.

All the bags I've seen so far are aimed towards people with A LOT more stuff, any advice on a more stream lined one?

Preferably one that will last me as I upgrade my fostex to a SD 702 for instance?

Thanks
C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Petrol.](http://www.petrolbags.com/Sound-Bags)
I use the small mixer bag myself for my SD702. Small but carry anything i need except zeppelins and stands of course... :)